# User Control - dependency property to Change Image Issues

Tags: wpf, user-controls

i'm having issues setting the Image from a dependency property.  It seems like the trigger doesnt fire.  I just want hide/show and image, or set the source if possible.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HasSingleValueProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("HasSingleValue", typeof(bool), typeof(LevelControl), new 

FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public bool HasSingleValue
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasSingleValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasSingleValueProperty, value); }
    }

 public LevelControl()
{
this.InitializeComponent();

//this.DataContext = this;
LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
}

  //Control Markup
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image x:Name="xGreenBarClientTX" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="13" Margin="7,8.5,7,0" 
           Stretch="Fill" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="47" 
           Canvas.Left="181.67" 
           d:LayoutOverrides="Height" >
            <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasSingleValue}" Value="True">
                        <Setter  Property="Opacity"  Value="100"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasSingleValue}" Value="False">
                        <Setter  Property="Opacity"  Value="0"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go
you have to update your binding as follows (I used Ellipse instead for testing)

```
<Window 
x:Name="myWindow">



<Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasSingleValue, ElementName=myWindow}" Value="True">
            <Setter  Property="Visibility"  Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasSingleValue, ElementName=myWindow}" Value="False">
            <Setter  Property="Visibility"  Value="Hidden"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then you need to set HasSingleValue
I created two buttons to show and hide my Ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble may be with how you're trying to update the dependency property because I've made a slight alteration to your example to verify the bindings and such do work as expected. I had suspected that there may be a problem with binding to a property on the grid's data context from the image, but that appears to be fine.

It wasn't clear what kind of class you were providing as a data context, but if you're using dependency properties then it needs to be a DependencyObject.

I've provided an example here using a text block and a toggle button to change the dependency property. (assuming you're using code-behind)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="xGreenBarClientTX" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="13" Margin="7,8.5,7,0"  
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Width="200" 
       Canvas.Left="181.67" >
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasSingleValue}" Value="True">
                        <Setter  Property="Text"  Value="Is Set"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasSingleValue}" Value="False">
                        <Setter  Property="Text"  Value="Is Not Set"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Toggle" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

and the code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = new VM() { HasSingleValue = true };
}

private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    var vm = LayoutRoot.DataContext as VM;
    if ( vm == null )
        return;

    vm.HasSingleValue = !vm.HasSingleValue;
}

public class VM : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasSingleValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register( "HasSingleValue", typeof( bool ), typeof( VM ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault ) );

    public bool HasSingleValue
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue( HasSingleValueProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( HasSingleValueProperty, value ); }
    }

}
```